# Accessing the elements of tuple

Tags: python, oop

This problem takes few space separated inputs (split them into a list of tuples) and returns the total cost of products multiply by its quantity.
While solving this problem , I have got stuck in the method `Cost`.This isn't giving me the proper output.

**Problem I am facing:**

1. Cost method isn't giving me sum of product price
2. If I print tuple list - `print(part2.create_list_of_tuples())` ; I am getting unexpected list of tuples. example -

My given input-

input formula - `sl.no.<space>product<space>quantity<space>price`

```
Enter an entry: 1 book 3 20
Enter an entry: 2 pen 10 5
Enter an entry: 3 notebook 10 10
Enter an entry: 0
```

Output-

```
[(1, 'book', 3, 20), (1, 'book', 3, 20), (2, 'pen', 10, 5), (1, 'book', 3, 20), (2, 'pen', 10, 5), (3, 'notebook', 10, 10)]
```

Actual output should be-

```
Product price 210
[(1, 'book', 3, 20), (2, 'pen', 10, 5), (3, 'notebook', 10, 10)]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
class products:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sl_no = list()
        self.item_name = list()
        self.purchase_amount = list()
        self.purchase_cost = list()
        self.list_of_tuples = list()

    def create_list_of_tuples(self):
        self.list_of_tuples = list(zip(self.sl_no, self.item_name, self.purchase_amount, self.purchase_cost))
        return self.list_of_tuples


    def Cost(self):
        Sum_purchase_cost = 0
        for j in self.list_of_tuples:
            Sum_purchase_cost += ((j[2]) * (j[3]))
        print(f"Product price {Sum_purchase_cost}")

part2=product()
tuplelist = []
while True:
    a = input('Enter an entry: ')
    if a == str(0):
        break
    tuplelist.append(tuple(a.strip().split()))
    for i in tuplelist:
        part2.sl_no.append(int(i[0]))
        part2.item_name.append(i[1])
        part2.purchase_amount.append(int(i[2]))
        part2.purchase_cost.append(int(i[3]))
part2.Cost()
print(part2.create_list_of_tuples())
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `for` loop is executed for every element already present in `tuplelist`, every time a new element has been added.

Either unindent that loop (so that it runs only once), or store the newly created tuple in a variable `i` and remove the `for` loop statement (but not the loop body).